# How to install node package globally - the right way?

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, node.js

I am trying to avoid installing common Node packages redundantly for each user. I would like to install certain common Node packages globally. However, on Arch Linux, I encounter permissions issues.

```
npm install [package] -g
```

fails with message:

> Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules

This succeeds:

```
sudo npm install [package] -g
```

However, then we get errors like this when a regular user tries to use the package:

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/lib/node_modules/[package]/lib/[file].js'

What is the right way to do this, assuming we are required to install some packages globally. EDIT: see the reason for the requirements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481432/shell-programming-in-javascript-with-node-how-to-deploy-the-completed-cli-app).

Comment: My recommendation: **Don't**. I tried, and it breaks horribly over time when dependency hell rears its ugly head. After that experience, I always install packages per repository. Even if it means wasting disk space, and having to cleanup node_modules from time to time.

Comment: I now realize I did not ask the question I needed to ask. Therefore, I created a new (hopefully better) question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481432/shell-programming-in-javascript-with-node-how-to-deploy-the-completed-cli-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general **all packages should be installed locally**. This ensures you can have multiple applications running on different versions (like needed) of the same package. A global package-update might unleash hell in terms of broken dependencies and compatibility.

Do a **global install when** a package provides an executable command you want to run from the shell.

**BUT** if there is an already globally installed package you want to use in development: use `npm link <global-package>`. This will create a local link to that package (*working only with npm >= 1.0 and with an OS supporting symlinks*).

For further information read:

1. [npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)
2. [npm-1-0-link](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-link/)

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't answer my intended question. I now realize I did not ask the question well. Therefore, I created a new (hopefully better) question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481432/shell-programming-in-javascript-with-node-how-to-deploy-the-completed-cli-app